# How to change the base branch of a branch

Tags: github, branching-and-merging

Currently, I have a branch a main branch `sprint-25` from where I have created `feature/proj-121` and started working on it. This branch has not been merged into `sprint-25`   as work is still going on but I have created another branch `fixes/proj-141` from `feature/proj-121`  to fix one another bug and commit and push the changes , now when I create Merge Request(MR), it contains all the changes files which were committed `feature/proj-121` branch that is obvious because I have created this branch from the `feature/proj-121`

Yes. now the issue is that `feature/proj-121` has 125 file changes and `fixes/proj-141` had only 3 files changes and when we Merge request it shows 128 files changes but I want only 3 files changes.

I am aware of using *cherry-pick* will need a new branch but is there any way we can preserve the same branch name but change the base branch.

Now My issue is how to realign the branch `fixes/proj-141` with `sprint-25`  so that MR contain only that commit and files which were changed for this branch only.

Comment: You lost me.  Can you add a diagram which shows the workflow you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , yes Sure. here it is : https://imgur.com/a/Q2HZg2i

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: He basically wants `fixes/proj-141` to start at `sprint-25` and not at `feature/proj-121`. Which is pretty hard to obtain now because you already pushed everything if I got you correct

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Updated the question too

Answer (score 0):

The branch you created for the fix was created from branch feature/proj-121, and hence all the issues. What you can do now is create a new branch and cherry pick these changes using git cherry-pick and then raise a merge request.

For more details on cherry-pick, please refer https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: so doing `cherry-pick` will create a new branch to commit but my requirement is to put the same branch name `fixes/vir-141` is that possible?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, as you have already created the branch from feature/proj-121and pushed to remote.

Comment: If you have already pushed these branches publicly, then you probably can't do exactly what you want.  Find another way.

Comment: You can delete the remote branch and try to create a new branch with the same name.

Comment: there is no such command `cherry-drop` so that we pick and drop

Comment: No, there is not